# Would polyamide 6 filaments be effected by an acrylic micro emulsion?

Tags: polymers

I would like to hear more about: Will an acrylic micro emulsion applied to polyamide 6 filaments (that have been coated with PTFE) weaken the filaments?
Also would polyester filaments be effected?

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help).